# Unable to ping into a specific Linux computer on my network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I am getting 100% packet loss when attempting to ping the ip address of an old Dell tower on my local network.

It definitely has Linux running on it, it is connected to the network via an Ethernet cable from the Ethernet port to a  NETGEAR ProSAFE 16-Port Gigabit Smart Managed Switch (GS716T).

The switch has a green light on for the port number that the cable is plugged into, so the problem is likely not the Ethernet cable itself.

What other possible troubleshooting steps can I take here? I have already force-rebooted the computer (since it is sitting on a rack, in a server configuration, with no monitor).

Below are some ping stats for 10 packets:

`10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9072ms`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: Just tried telnet and ssh, and neither worked.

Comment: Can you operate that computer? Does the network look working on it?

Comment: What do you mean by operate?

Comment: Use keyboard, mouse, monitor, see if it is connected.

Comment: I can try a monitor/peripherals. Thanks. I will update what happens when I connect these.

Comment: Probably you don't plan to have it running with those peripherals... I mean, but if you can configure it with them it would definitely be much easier do to troubleshooting on that computer itself.

Comment: Plugged in monitor. Says that "Drive 2 not detected". It has only listed the drives available and says "Press Ctrl-I to enter configuration utility".

It may be a hard drive issue. I will run diagnostics and google around. Thanks for the monitor idea though!

Comment: I will write this into an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to figure out the problem from some other computer on the same network.

I understand you may want to run that machine without peripherals, like a server or something, but if you would like to do troubleshooting, it would be much easier if it is possible to attached some peripherals to that computer so you can operate on it directly, and get input/output. For example, you can see if the machine gets an IP address on itself pretty easily with just `ifconfig`.

---

Then the OP says the machine didn't even boot correctly because of a failed hard drive, so this is no longer a networking problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out all I had to do was press F1 to continue and the OS loaded!

Thanks.